# Value of hazard ratio in survival analysis

Tags: survival

I have a dataset with lung cancer, which should be processed by survival analysis. The independent variables are a series of some radiomic features. The goal of this research is to look for some features which might play important roles in patients' surviving time. As a regular step, I performed the univariate analysis with coxph(R function) model. The estimated hazard ratio(exp(coefficient)) for most variables is below 10. However, some features have extremely high hazard ratio, for example, 10^4. Can I trust this result? If not, is there a general range for the hazard ratio to be considered reasonable?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "reasonable"?  Without any context it isn't reasonable to even answer this question, because survival analyses techniques can be applied so broadly to so many kinds of objects over so many different time frames.

Comment: I expand the question a little bit, hope that it is clear now.

Comment: Have you normalized the features prior to training? For example if one of your features is "smoking cigarettes made of asbestos", then give how rare and impactful it is, it could have a huge coefficient.

Comment: @AlexR  Yes, I did. Sometimes, large coefficients appear in multiple variables survival fitting.